# Making a Java Bean aplicattion

Tags: java, netbeans, javabeans

I'm trying to create my own Java Beans in order to use them in a new project just by dropping them, the problem is that I'm forced to used the no parametres constructors but I need to use the ones that has parametres, so basicly I have a GUI in a single class and I'm using other classes to respond for actions, so how can I use the whole program as a Java Bean and make it work with the constructor I need?.
Thanks all for your help.

Comment: You can have multiple constructors for the same class one with no parameters that leaves things at default values and one with arguments for convenience.

Comment: The problem is that when I drag and drop the bean, the auto-generated code cannot be modify

Comment: How are you generating this unmodifiable code? To drag a bean onto the GUI builder it would have to already exist and have been modifiable.  New genereated JFrame's and JPanel;s are modifiable.

Comment: With Netbeans, I created a JFrame Form and then with the GUI builder assistant I dragged the bean, so there's when the unmodifiable code appears.

Comment: So the bean itself can be modified to add another constructor, correct?

Comment: yes, The bean is supposed to manage the connection and display to an Access database, so that's my problem because I don't know how to make the bean to use the DB file on the project source and display it correctly, because when it's just a program it works perfectly, but when I used it like a bean it just do nothing.

Comment: Perhaps if you post the relevant code, I can make more specific suggestions.  I would make the default no args constructor setup the bean but leave it unconnected, add a separate public function (eg. connect())  to have bean make the connection and provide any needed info such as file location. The code in the JFrame that embeds the bean would call the connect() function either in its own constructor after initComponents() returns or in response to some event.